# When i fetch comments for particular Playlist i am getting all comments. And How can i get the other properties of comments?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> This is My Playlist Schema:
> when i fetch the comments for particular playlist i got only ids for the comments. How can i send all detail of comments of particular playlist to the front end?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// const Video = require('./Video');
const User = require('./User');
const Comment = require('./Comment');

const VideoSchema = new Schema(
    {
        url: {
            type: String
            // required: true
        },
        shortDescription: {
            type: String,
            max: 120
            // required: true
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            min: 20,
            max: 200
        },
        // createdOn: {
        //  type: Date,
        //  default: Date.now
        // },
        createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        uploadedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
        // uploadedOn: {
        //  type: Date,
        //  default: Date.now
        // }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

const PlaylistSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        detail: {
            type: String,
            max: 100
        },
        tag: [ { type: String } ],
        // user: {
        //  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //  ref: 'User'
        // },
        uploadBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        videos: [ VideoSchema ],
        // videos: [ { type: String } ],
        // createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        updateBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        // updateOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        comments: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' } ]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

module.exports = Playlist = mongoose.model('Playlist', PlaylistSchema);
```

> This is my Comment Schema

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = require('./User');

const CommentSchema = new Schema(
    {
        createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        detail: {
            type: String,
            max: 200
        },
        // createdOn: {
        //  type: Date,
        //  default: Date.now
        // },
        // updatedOn: {
        //  type: Date,
        //  default: Date.now
        // },
        updatedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

CommentSchema.pre('remove', async function(next) {
    try {
        let foundUser = await User.findById(this.createdBy);
        foundUser.comments.remove(this.id);
        await User.save();
        return next();
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error);
    }
});

module.exports = Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

This is the function which will run when i fetch for comments

```
 exports.getComments = async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        console.log('request came for fetching comment');
    let foundPlaylist = await Playlist.findById(req.params.playlist_id).populate('comments');
    console.log('foundPlaylist:', foundPlaylist);

    

    let foundComments = foundPlaylist.comments.map(async (comment) => {
        return await Comment.findById(comment._id).populate('createdBy', { firstName: true });
    });
        return res.status(200).json(comments);
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error);
    }
};
```

> when i fetch the comments for particular playlist i got only ids for
> the comments. How can i send all detail of comments of particular
> playlist to the front end?

//Routes

```
  router.route('/').get(getComments);
```

//index route

```
   app.use('/api/users/:id/playlists/:playlist_id/comments', loginRequired, ensureCorrectUser, commentAuthRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments field was defined to only contain a dbref:

```
comments: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' } ]
```

To retrieve the matching comment documents, use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: I populate the comments but still i am not able to get createdBy(firstName) i just got only id of the users. I used async await but i got only empty comments object. can you help me with it?